R (networkD3) Sankey diagram: Moving labels of the source nodes to the left and labels of target nodes to the right?
I'm creating a Sankey diagram and couldn't figure out how to move labels of the nodes to the right or left side. The only thing I fugured out that sinksRight = FALSE moves labels of target nodes to the right side, which is good, but don't know what to do about moving labels of source nodes to the left. Also, maybe You could help how to put nodes in the specific order at the final HTML stage using only the code and it'll look perfect square or rectungular shape, so I don't need to manually rearrange it in HTML.
I`m using this code:
if (!require(networkD3)) install.packages("networkD3")
if (!require(dplyr)) install.packages("dplyr")

# Load the necessary libraries
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

# Define the nodes using the data from the Nodes DataFrame
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Mežs", "Apmežots LIZ", "Aramzeme", "Nekopts LIZ", 
                             "Zālājs", "VK", "PV", "PO", "AN", "GL", "PG", "AL", "TZ", "TP", "TA"))

# Define the links using the data from the Links DataFrame
links <- data.frame(
    source = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
               0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    target = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
               10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
               14, 14, 14, 14, 14),
    value = c(35, 18, 9, 41, 9, 1208, 949, 267, 633, 656, 79, 9, 0, 9, 0, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 374, 236, 72, 235, 85, 
              714, 319, 156, 239, 257, 261, 176, 48, 108, 67, 1133, 360, 17, 443, 72, 70, 10, 1, 24, 0, 27, 0, 0, 4, 0)
)

# Create and visualize the Sankey diagram with adjusted height and width
p <- sankeyNetwork(
    Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
    Source = "source", Target = "target",
    Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
    units = "TWh", fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 30,
    height = 500, width = 500
)

# Print the Sankey diagram
print(p)```

